# Single word for 'and thus', 'as such' or 'in other words'

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a list to describe a subject, like:

> He's handsome, articulate, immensely intelligent, physically fit, but spends most of his time tinkering in his garage … ***in other words***, Tony Stark!

What single word can I substitute for the expression *in other words,* or *to summarize,* in sentences such as the above?

Comment: I hope this isn't you describing yourself in a resume/online profile.

Comment: Absolutely not! I don't have a garage.

Comment: What exactly is your *[in other words]* supposed to convey? That *only* the named example matches the preceding description? That the example *exactly* fits the description? That the example is (or in the opinion of the speaker, *should be*) well-known to everyone as the prototypical example of the description?

Comment: The fact that you said "probably Latin, though I'm not sure." makes me think the word you are looking for is **voilà** (which is French).

Comment: Hmm, no, it's not voilà, Chris, though it may be French!

Comment: FumbleFingers: I'd say the latter is most true in this particular instance. :)

Comment: _e.g._ works in some, but not all instances.

Comment: It's not ipso facto, but I do like that, thank you! Added to my list of words to find a reason to use!

Comment: I'm thinking, for some reason, it may be used in place of 'see also' in some instances...

Comment: Essentially the question in this case is "what word did I forget", and the sole criterion for what will be accepted as an answer is "yes, that's the word I forgot". While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one is unlikely to help future readers and should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Ergo, perhaps...?

[Ergo](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ergo): consequently, therefore, so, then, thus, hence, accordingly, in consequence, etc.

Ergo is Latin for therefore.

> - Cogito *ergo* sum (I think, therefore I am).
>     -She was the sole beneficiary of the will, *ergo* the prime suspect.
> - Perhaps because in that direction lay the least known areas of Barsoom, and, e*rgo*, Romance, Mystery, and Adventure. - E. R. Burroughs
> - ...I am a talker, then the true reasoning runs that since all men of sense should avoid me, and thou hast not avoided me, but art at the present moment eating herrings with me under a holly-bush, *ergo* you are no man of sense, which is exactly what I have been dinning into your long ears ever since I first clapped eyes on your sunken chops. - Sir Arthur Conan Doyle

Comment: Thank you, this would work but it's not the one I'm (not) thinking of... don't you just hate it when the word is right there but it won't come out?

Comment: I like this answer, although it's not the specific one they're after, it works...

Answer (score 2):

*In short,*

> "He's handsome, articulate, immensely intelligent, physically fit but spends most of his time tinkering in his garage, **in short,** Tony Stark!"

Answer (score 1):

"He's handsome, articulate, immensely intelligent, physically fit but spends most of his time tinkering in his garage – in sum, Tony Stark!"

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for...

> "ie" or "id est" - that is to say; in other words

Comment: Id est sounds close, I think it's that kind of thing, though I'm still not sure it's the one I'm looking for. If I don't find it, I'll use that, thanks! :)

Comment: "Thus" or "hence" maybe? I don't think these are an exact fit really though... :)